# geometryType property of Vector Layers in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, geometry, editing

### **ORIGINAL:**

I have a couple questions that are focused around the geometryType property with vector layers.  When you create a vector layer you can set the geometryType property to limit the geometry types the layer supports...

> {String} geometryType allows you to limit the types of geometries this layer supports.  This should be set to something like “OpenLayers.Geometry.Point” to limit types. -- [OpenLayers API Docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.geometryType)

but in the Vector.js file the code is looking for an object when checking the geometry

```
 if (this.geometryType &&
          !(feature.geometry instanceof this.geometryType)) {
            var throwStr = OpenLayers.i18n('componentShouldBe',
                      {'geomType':this.geometryType.prototype.CLASS_NAME});
            throw throwStr;
          }
```

*Is this a typo in the API Docs or am I doing something wrong here?*

On a related note if I set the geometryType of a VectorLayer to be **OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon** and then try to edit geometry of features in that layer it doesn't want to work because it tries to insert **OpenLayers.Geometry.Point** geometries into the layer to represent the draggable vertices.

*Is there a something built in to get around this or do I need to write something to handle this?*

### **UPDATE:**

This seems to work but I'll be running more tests.

*Vector.js*

```
    // Override for geometryType.
    var geometryType = options && options.geometryType !== undefined ? options.geometryType : this.geometryType;
```

*ModifyFeature.js*

```
// Where "addFeatures" exist I've tacked on the geometryType
this.layer.addFeatures([this.radiusHandle], {silent: true, geometryType: OpenLayers.Geometry.Point});
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Looks like a bug or document inconsistency to me. I think you should open a ticket at http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FilingTickets

Comment: Looks like a ticket has already been opened (3 years ago :/) http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug.](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2011)

You can try modifying vector.js to what this thread suggests might be a solution (at the bottom)

If it does work, post back on that thread letting them know what worked for you.